# How to resolve "ORA-00904: Invalid identifier insert statement"

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to add a column to my users table but I get an error every time I try to create a new user I end up getting the error "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "IMPORTED": invalid identifier".
In the database my column is created but I still get an error when i try to create a user.

I'm trying to create a column that receives true or false in my user table.
When I try to create a new user by jpa I end up getting an error

My Model:

```
@Column(name = "IMPORTED")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Eboolean imported;
```

My query:

```
alter table USER add IMPORTED VARCHAR2(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is not (entirely) true. Table name certainly isn't `user`:

```
SQL> create table user (id number);
create table user (id number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Why? Because it is *reserved* for function that returns currently logged user:

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SCOTT

SQL>
```

Therefore, table name is *something else*; or, if it *is* `user`, then you must have created it by enclosing its name into double quotes, but then you have to use double quotes every time, matching letter case every time:

```
SQL> create table "user" (id number);

Table created.
```

Presuming that this is what you have, then:

```
SQL> alter table "user" add imported varchar2(1);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

Furthermore, error you specified is

> ORA-00904: invalid identifier

If you got it when inserting a row into a table, it means that there's no such column in that table. Possible causes:

- you misspelled its name
- there's really no such column there
- double quotes and letter case matching issue

Presuming that column exists (see above `alter table`), `insert` also works:

```
SQL> insert into "user" (id, imported) values (1, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from "user";

        ID IMPORTED
---------- ----------
         1 0

SQL>
```